# Boost.Python, how to return a numpy arrray from C++ array?

Tags: c++, boost-python

I defined a 2d and 3d C++ array

```
// ROW x COL
auto ** arr1 = (double **)malloc(ROW * sizeof(double *));
for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) arr1[i] = (double *)malloc(COL * sizeof(double));

// ROW x COL1 x COL2
auto *** arr2 = (double ***)malloc(ROW * sizeof(double **));
for (int i=0; i < ROW; i++) {
    arr2[i] = (double **)malloc(COL1 * sizeof(double *));
    for (int j=0; j < COL1; j++) {
        arr2[i][j] = (double *)malloc(COL2 * sizeof(double));
    }
}
```

How can I convert these arrays into numpy arrays with low overhead using `Boost.Python`?

Comment: There are no arrays in that piece of code. Also don't cast the result of malloc but use `new` instead. Even better, use `std::vector`.

Comment: @Swordfish thank you for your suggestion, I will try `std::vector`.